# MongoDB: How can I store files (Word, Excel, etc.)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've yet to look into storing files such as Word, Excel, etc. into MongoDB seriously and I want to know - am I able to store whole docx or excel files in MongoDB and then RETRIEVE them via querying?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using gridfs yes.

Gridfs is a storage specification. It is not built into the DB but instead into the drivers.

You can find out more here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS.

It's normal implementation is to break down your big documents into smaller ones and store those aprts in a chunks collection mastered by a fs.files collection which you query for your files.

Comment: If your binary files fit within the BSON size limit (currently 16MB) you should also consider storing the binary objects directly within single documents.  There is a wiki page with some suggestions on [When to use GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/When+to+use+GridFS).

Comment: Indeed, that is completely correct since it can cause unnessecary queries and allocation of space.

Answer (score 7):

MongoDB is a document database that stores JSON-like documents (called [BSON](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON)). Maximum size of a BSON object is [16 megabytes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents#Documents-MaximumDocumentSize), which may be too little for some use cases.

If you want to store binary data of arbitrary size, you can use GridFS (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification). GridFS automatically splits your documents (or any binary data) into several BSON objects ([usually 256k in size](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification)), so you only need to worry about storing and retriving complete documents (whatever their sizes are).

As far as I know, Mongoose doesn't support GridFS. However, you can use GridFS via [its native driver's GridStore](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/gridfs.html). Just run `npm install mongodb` and start hacking!

Comment: I know - that's why I said there was jesting in the title - I spose I should have circumvented that jest.

Does MongoDB have capability to "break up" Word or Excel into BSON and reassemble again upon querying?

Comment: MongoDB is not JSON and BSON is not JSON

Comment: Msx doc size if actually 16Mb

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Fixed.

Comment: Also due to memory allocation the default implemented size of a file chunk is also 256k not 16mb

Comment: Thanks. Clarified that as well!